# The Cassandra cluster has not been initialized yet

Tags: cassandra

We're implementing a machine translation engine on Ubuntu 20.04 that uses Cassandra. Everything works fine, until after a few hours we get the following message:

The Cassandra cluster has not been initialized yet and no host amongst the contact points can be reached, or no host can be contacted to set the keyspace.

Any pointers to where we should start looking?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an application error. It isn't a message that originates from a Cassandra cluster.

My guess is that at some point, it's possible that the nodes get overloaded and become unresponsive or maybe even crash (due to OOM). Check the Cassandra logs for clues.

If you update your question with a bit more detail, I'll be happy to update my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause, for anyone else who runs into this error: it was the memory. There was not enough of it. When we expanded the machine from 32 GB to 64 GB, all errors were gone. The system has been running stable for 48 hours now. Thank you very much for your help!